# Near js micro transactions/meta transactions relayer

Tags: nearprotocol

I really need your help with realization meta transactions on Near. I find this dock:
https://docs.near.org/develop/relayers/build-relayer
that have no examples and not described imports and also this one:
https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/master/packages/cookbook/transactions/meta-transaction.js
but after basic implementation I don't reached the correct result.
Please help to find out fresh docs or example of basic meta transaction implementation, or help to fix the usage of the correct one, to have possibility to delegate contract sign or at least near sending across signer account in meta transaction / relayer

Here is example of implementation:
[transaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZMLi.png)
[basic call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPWuJ.png)
after it I'm making the request from postman to my basic enpoint:
[postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trytD.png)
and after sign the result is:
[-32700] Parse error: Failed to decode transaction: Unexpected variant index: 143"

Answer (score 0):

```
 import { actionCreators } from "@near-js/transactions";   
  const result = await signerAccount.signAndSendTransaction({
  receiverId: receiverId,
  actions: [actionCreators.transfer(new BN(amount))],
});
```

This code is example, which you can rewrite.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).